# C# Datagridview issue

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to coding and trying to learn but have come across an error which is very annoying, I am trying to populate a data grid with the value selected from a dropdownlist and I am not sure why it is throwing up this error.

The program takes and enters into the Database the information fine, but when I expanded on the program to add a Datagridview so the user could see the entered information for a specific driver selected from the combobox

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sqlcon.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("display", sqlcon))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", driverSelect.SelectedValue);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        sqlcon.Close();
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

this is the error I get

> "System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.'" from this line. SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: seems driverSelect.SelectedValue is a DataRowView, and the reader is tryng to find che corrected map value. Make sure "@driver" is a scalar value.

Comment: The driverSelect.SelectedValue is taken from the dropdown list and entered as variable in the SQL stored procedure, removing the variable and the dataview populates which is equally frustrating.

Comment: A data-bound dropdown list has a DataTextField and a DataValueField. One is what the user sees, the other is the actual object you get when you access the SelectedValue. It looks like you want to get a property (not shown) of the selected value, not use the SelectedValue itself as the sql parameter.

Comment: This is the problem, the value is an Int so I don't understand why it is not returning the values to the datagridview.

Comment: But it is not an int. It is a DataRowView